# Nissan Versa 2007 Coolant Change Problem

Tags: nissan, cooling-system, coolant-leak, radiator-overflow, versa

So I changed my coolant, online it said I need 6 ltr but it only took 5 and that was including filling the overflow tank to the max level, I had it jacked one side high and tried to burp it. I took it for a drive for 30 min and on stopping  noticed that the level in the overflow had dropped an inch or so. Is that because as I drove it the air bubble got out and the radiator sucked the fluid it needs in or .....

On stopping I also noticed a few small drips of blue engine coolant on top of the air intake and on top of a few of the other areas not a lot, about 5 drops the size of a pea. Do you think I have a leak or could it be the overflow tank overflowing when driving as it’s still an inch of the max line. It has no leaks when at park I idle and I didn’t notice any leaks before the change and the overflow tank was always sitting an inch or two under what looked like half full. No water in the oil.

It’s not overheating and heater is working ok.

Would air in the system cause the overflow to overflow a little and be causing the small amount of coolant at driving speed ?

Comment: When you drained it - exactly how much came out? Did you check?

Comment: No I didn’t check , I wish I did now . Stupid mistake , I couldn’t find the sump drain plug either. Do you know if the recommended 6ltr includes the overflow tank ?

Comment: Most cars I have drained tend to leave the heater matrix full, which may be the 1 litre that you missed...

Comment: Any thoughts on the light splattering of clear blue coolant on top of air cleaner intake and a few other areas at the front ? Not sure if that’s the reason the overflow tank dropped for the maximum level line to an inch below or if I have a small leaks or leaks in the radiator. Thought I was doing a good thing for the old car before a road trip tomorrow now I’m worried